# How to prevent fake identites in zmq dealer-router pattern

Tags: sockets, zeromq, jeromq

I'm using the ZMQ pattern dealer/router.
In my project, a router is a server manager and a dealer is a client.

So I have many dealers and only one router.

Each dealer can send its own request along with its identity so that later on the router knows where to send the piece of information based on their identity. To be more specific the identity is a public key based on asymmetric encryption that both router and dealers come up with an agreement on before the handshake.

Everything runs smoothly and the router sends chunks of information on dealers based on their public key identities so we are all happy.

But!! What happened in the case that an attacker pretended dealers' identities by opening multiple connections and using their public keys as identities? How can we prevent a situation like this? How the router can identify this case? Is there any way for a router to check their IP and ban illegal IPs that are not known? I am so confused how can I come up with that riddle?

Comment: I'm confused. If you're using asymmetric encryption, then the dealers should be *signing* data with their private key, and the router should be validating that signature with the public key. It should not be possible for anyone to impersonate a dealer unless they are able to steal the private key.

Comment: @larsks let me give you an example a dealer uses as his identity his public key and sends a signed message to the router if a malicious user opens a socket to the router and pretends the same identity with same public key as the dealer he will manage to create chaos ok i agree the router will recognize the fraud with signature validity but if there are two same identical identities how to know in which node to send back the response